# Format Date and Time into DTG

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a row where users enter in various type of data in the date in there are different formats that I want to standardize. For example

```
12/21/2014 1900
```

This is one possible format I would like for the `<td>` to change it into DTG format which is

```
DD-HHMMZ-MMM-YY
```

Day, Hours in 24 format, Minutes, instead of p.m./a.m. I need Z for zulu, Month and year

How do I have this change once the user enters the data? I was looking at the onchange for javascript but I am not completely sure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming what you're asking is how to force the input to update after the user enters the date information. I'm assuming you know how you're going to format the date based on the given input.

This example shows you how to use jquery's .change() to update the input after something is entered.  http://jsfiddle.net/Z5B25/

The basic code looks like:

```
$('.date').change(function(){
    $(this).val('Computed/formatted Date');
});
```

Though this is not specific to your usage.

Comment: Correct I want to force the input to update to the format I provided. The date will inputted by the user it will not be derived by JQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: Exactly.  That's what my example demonstrates. It simply demonstrates how to use .change() to update the input.  You would have to fill in the logic of actually computing the date. Here's a more detailed example (including a possible date conversions) http://jsfiddle.net/nNrqf/43/

Comment: Thanks for the example. I know absolutely nothing about JQuery. thanks for the example I will try to work it out further. I did not realize how much code went into changing the date into that format

Comment: I found this website [link](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/date/examples.php) when I enter the the format of dd-HHmm-NNN-yy then click on format current date it outputs it correctly into an alert. Is there a way to take the onclick code and implement it into what I need?